# How do I check the database if it has exactly one record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

How do I check if there is exactly one record in active-record?
I can do

```
@items.count == 1
```

but lately I notice it takes 90ms while other queries take 20ms.
Sometimes the count method for some things take a long time.
So is there a method that just checks for 1?

```
@items.only_one_exist?
```

Comment: This may be faster, `@items.count_by_sql(SELECT * FROM [table] LIMIT 2)` It will either select 1 or 2 (or 0) and will get its result faster than actually counting everything.

Comment: Actually `@items.take(2).count` is what you should use once you've already obtained your results.

Comment: so, i tried take(2) the sql looks the same. There is also limit(2). I onder which is better

Comment: I'm not sure how Ruby decides whether to query again vs. look at the obtained results. Here's what I see when I do something similar `@countTest = Clm.where("dcity = ?", 'Chicago')` - in controller, `<%= @countTest.inspect %>
<%= @countTest.count %>
<%= @countTest.take(2).count %>` - in view. Results are the records, 158827 and, 2. And the SQL time `Clm Load (1080.7ms)  SELECT 'clms'.* FROM 'clms' WHERE (dcity = 'Chicago')`
   `(70.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 'clms' WHERE (dcity = 'Chicago')`
  `Clm Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  'clms'.* FROM 'clms' WHERE (dcity = 'Chicago') LIMIT 2`

Comment: I looked in to `.take` vs `.limit`, `.take` returns an array, while `.limit` returns a relation. It just happens that `.count` exists for both and at least in this case does the same thing. I have no idea which would be faster - on one hand you convert the relation to an array first, on the other hand activerecord `.count` may be slower than array `.count` (or `.length` is what should probably be used.)

Answer (score 0):

The `count` method as you have it is the only way, and yes - it will take generally take much longer than a select because there's more steps involved in calculating that total.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@items.one?`/`Item.one?` method